# iTunesConnect - uploading an archive stuck

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an archive to iTunes Connect, the app works fine and the validation does not give any error but when I upload the archive to the store the uploading process bar keeps going back to empty state. It goes almost to the middle and then return to the beginning. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: SNos, it depends on internet bandwidth and iTunesConnect server availability.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you to export an ipa and then submit via Application Loader.